# html element to hover over another element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

how does one position a html element in front of another so that when one a particular element is hovered over the new element will appear in front of it.
here is my code:

```
<div class="third">
        <label> Enter Password: </label>
        <input type="text" name="pword1" class="iBox" id="pword1" onmouseout="HideToolTip()" onmouseover="ShowToolTip()" onkeyup="allFunctions()" placeholder="choose a password" autocomplete="off">
        <p id="tooltipbox" style="visibility:hidden">Password must be between 8-16 characters, contain an uppercase, lowercase, number and special character</p>
    </div>
```

i have a tooltip and it works so far. but when i hover over the textarea it shoves the element below it downwards so that the tooltip can fit in on the page and when i move the mouse so to 'unhover' it, the element re positions upwards. i want a way when i hover, a message box is brought to the front and all the elements underneath do not move. much like when you hover any links on this page, they bring up a little dialog box which is only there on hover and DOES NOT reposition other elements on the page.

Comment: Use absolute positioning: `<p id="tooltipbox" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden">`

Comment: @gknicker thanks. would upvote but not answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `z-index` and `position` property; for example:

```
p#tooltipbox{
   z-index:1000;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;//move the element to the top of div.third of div.third
   left:0;//if you want to move the element to the left;
}
div.third{
   position:relative;
}
```

here's more information
[z-index property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)
[position propery](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I created a jsfiddle for you. Click the following link to see an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/xL7j4k6g/

Refer to the link above, but here is also the code:

```css
.fieldarea {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 50%;
}
.fieldarea label {
    width: 35%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.fieldarea input {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.tooltipbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    max-width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.fieldarea:hover .tooltipbox {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="fieldarea">
        <label for="pword1">Enter Password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="pword1" placeholder="choose a password" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="tooltipbox">Password must be between 8-16 characters, contain an uppercase, lowercase, number and special character</div>
    </div>
<div class="fieldarea">
        <label for="pword1">Enter Password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="pword1" placeholder="choose a password" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="tooltipbox">Password must be between 8-16 characters, contain an uppercase, lowercase, number and special character</div>
    </div>
```

(This doesn't look "cool" but works. I'd recommend looking into CSS3 transitions to some nice transformation touches - e.g. fade in the tooltip on hover.)

Thanks,
David

Comment: how would you get my tooltip to fade in slowly? at the moment it is just abrupt like yours. im not using hover either so i cant use fade with that. thanks

Comment: I just did a quick search. Here is an example: http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/   I'm also going to update my example to include an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning and jQuery. This is not perfect but a simple example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box1').hover(function() {
    $('.box2').toggleClass('active')
  })
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
.box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100;
  background-color: red;
}
.active {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```